# How to add few options to UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

There is way to add few options to imagePicker sourceType?

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options is specific to the Camera app and is not available through the API.

You should file an enhancement request at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

```
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = true.  // use this
imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = .FullScreen
```

If you make your own custom than you can create custom view

```
 imagePicker.cameraOverlayView = YourView
```